# Vite packaging configuration, how to merge small files?

Tags: vite

When using the default configuration of vite (2.9.5) to package, some components are very small, maybe only 0.2k, and they will also be packaged into a single file. How to merge these small files into one file?

For example, I have 6 small sub-components a, b, c, d, e, f on a parent page. If each sub-component is packaged into separate js and css, the browser will frequently request resources when loading the web page.

so,

I want to package together subcomponents a, b, c, d, e, f, etc., or

Package a, b, c, d, e, f pages in the resource file of the parent page,

How should I configure it?

Answer (score 4):

vite is packaged by rollup, you can configure the output.manualChunks configuration of rollup. [Documentation](https://rollup.docschina.org/guide/en/#outputmanualchunks)

vite.config.js

```js
build: {
     rollupOptions: {
       output:{
         manualChunks(id) {
             if (id.includes('components')) { // Package the files in the components file into components.js
                 return 'components'
             }
         }
     }
}
```